# Doctrine multiple level inheritance mapping

Tags: php, database, oop, orm, doctrine-orm

I have four types of products which I would like to map to a Doctrine ORM structure on a MySQL RDBMS. The products are `PrepaidProduct`, `PostpaidProduct`, `MobilePrepaidProduct`, `MobilePostpaidProduct` with the following structure:

```
abstract class Product {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $price;

    ...
}

class PrepaidProduct extends Product {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $credit;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PrepaidDiscount")
     */
    private $prepaidDiscounts;
}

class PostpaidProduct extends Product {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BundleMapping")
     */
    private $bundleMappings;
}

class MobilePrepaidProduct extends PrepaidProduct {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Device")
     */
    private $device;
}

class MobilePostpaidProduct extends PostpaidProduct {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Device")
     */
    private $device;
}
```

The main idea is that I would like to use a service (factory) that will use the basic class structure of the `PostpaidProduct` class to create a structure of the corresponding bundle mapping, so I think I would need this as a mapped super class.

In my opinion the way to go would be to have two separate tables, one for `PostpaidProduct` and one for `PrepaidProduct`, and have a Single Table Inheritance on those for `MobilePostpaidProduct`/`PostpaidProduct` and `MobilePrepaidProduct`/`PrepaidProduct`.

What do you guys think? Any thoughts on best way to model this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a RDBMS layer [MySQL, Postgre] as I think, your proposal is the best choice in my opinion.

If subclasses have **little* more attributes, possibly relationships most of all, you are actually promoting composition and your data representation won't be sparse [i.e. you won't have many empty fields in the main table].

On the other hand, if you want to stick with composition only [which is more advisable in most cases] - is `$device` the only additional relationship in Mobile classes? If so, you could write a `findAllMobileProducts` method in your repository class that would return every product where device is not null, and so on.